# Actionscript, BorderContainer.addElement(...) doesn't work?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

i have this:

```
public class AditionalPane extends BorderContainer {
     //.....

       private function storeRetrievedData(e : Event) : void {
        var titleLabel : Label = new Label();
        titleLabel.text = "Members: ";
        titleLabel.height = 100;
        titleLabel.x = 1;
        titleLabel.y = 1;
        //titleLabel.visible = true;
        super.addElement(titleLabel);

     //.....
}
```

the problem is that it doesn't display nothing on the screen where is the place for **titleLabel**. Only the pane, without content (items).
What's the problem?

Comment: You might want to provide the code that defines the instance of AdditionalPane, and also check if your storeRetrievedData function actually runs.

Comment: resolved! My BorderContainer was under another one partially! So this was the problem ...!!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your titleLabel has a width?  A zero width would, effectively, make it invisible.

A few other thoughts:

Would would you do "super.addElement()" instead of "this.addElement()"?  I would expect both to work, but it is unusual syntax.

Under normal circumstances, your skin class should be positioning and sizing the titleLabel.  Do you have a skin class?

Normally you would set other properties, such as 'text', in the partAdded method.  So your class might be re-factored to be something like this:

```
public class AditionalPane extends BorderContainer {
     public function AditionalPane ():void{
      this.setStyle("skinClass", mySkin);
     }

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var titleLabel : Label;

    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void { 
     if (instance == titleLabel){
        titleLabel.text = "Members: ";
     }
    }
}
```

A Skin Class would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
            [HostComponent("com.something.AdditionalPane")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <s:Label id="titleLabel" x="1" y="1" height="100" />


</s:SparkSkin>
```

Comment: @artaxerxe Why was this answer unaccepted?  Is there something wrong w/ it?  If so, we should update this information.  Or do you have a better/more up to date answer now?  If so, you should answer your own question for future readers of this question.